# zeroClipBoard swf not loading into html

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard

I am trying to see if I can use Zeroclipboard, so I am using this code here: http://pastebin.com/Pu0CstAu  but the alert is not shown, and I can't use the functionality. Is there something missing am not doing?

Thanks for any thought.

Edit: Added code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\rich\Downloads\zeroclipboard-master\dist\zeroclipboard.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>
        <button id="target-to-copy" data-clipboard-target="clipboard-text" class="">Click To Copy</button><br>
        <textarea name="clipboard-text" id="clipboard-text" cols="30" rows="10">            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mattis lacus nibh, ac

sollicitudin sapien accumsan in. Mauris euismod posuere tellus luctus sodales.
            Fusce a consectetur massa, non tincidunt mauris. Phasellus a rutrum libero. Praesent tempus urna et nisi aliquam convallis. Fusce porttitor justo condimentum orci euismod,

pulvinar congue magna vestibulum.
            Sed gravida eleifend justo, id ultrices tellus porttitor nec. Nam porttitor gravida tempor. In libero ante, euismod ac fermentum nec, gravida ut dolor. Nullam a pulvinar

ligula.
            Phasellus euismod rutrum risus non dapibus. Nullam pretium mauris vel fringilla pretium. Mauris faucibus risus vitae nulla dignissim imperdiet.
            Pellentesque elementum venenatis arcu, ut bibendum risus varius nec. Fusce eu tincidunt nunc. Duis sagittis dolor congue mauris tincidunt, eu condimentum eros rhoncus.
        </textarea>
    </p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

                var clientTarget = new ZeroClipboard( $("#target-to-copy"), {
              moviePath: "file:///C:/Users/rich/Downloads/zeroclipboard-master/dist/ZeroClipboard.swf",
              debug: false
            } );

            clientTarget.on( "load", function(clientTarget)
            {
            alert("client loaded");

                clientTarget.on( "complete", function(clientTarget, args) {
                    clientTarget.setText( args.text );

                } );
            } );

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you copy the code into the question? Thanks

Comment: Thanks yochannah, I pasted the code into the url: http://pastebin.com/Pu0CstAu

Comment: yep, but questions that have the code pasted directly into the question tend to get a more positive response. In my case, I'm behind a proxy and couldn't view that URL if I tried.

Comment: OK, I will modify the question.

Comment: Just modified the question.

Comment: Any thought yochannah?